# Shows specific digit of the output // deleting 0's from bigInteger

Tags: java, biginteger, factorial

How could I show only specific digit of an output?
How could I delete 0's from a bigInteger?

My Example:

Having a task to show number's factorial's last number that isn't 0.

```
Example:
1! = 1
2! = 2
3! = 6
4! = 4
5! = 2
6! = 2
```

Right now it just shows factorial.

```
import java.math.BigInteger;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main{
    // Returns Factorial of N
    static BigInteger factorial(int N){
        // Initialize result
        BigInteger f = new BigInteger("1"); // Or BigInteger.ONE

        // Multiply f with 2, 3, ...N
        for (int i = 2; i <= N; i++)
            f = f.multiply(BigInteger.valueOf(i));

        return f;
    }

    // Driver method
    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception
    {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        int n = scan.nextInt();
        System.out.println(factorial(n));
    }
}
```

Example vol2 --> Here I need a solution to remove 0's from biginteger:

```
import java.math.BigInteger;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main{
    // Returns Factorial of N
    static BigInteger factorial(int N){
        // Initialize result
        BigInteger f = new BigInteger("1"); // Or BigInteger.ONE

        // Multiply f with 2, 3, ...N
        for (int i = 2; i <= N; i++)
            f = f.multiply(BigInteger.valueOf(i));

        return f;
    }

    // Driver method
    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception
    {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        int n = scan.nextInt();
        BigInteger a = (factorial(n));
        BigInteger b, c;
        c = new BigInteger("10");
        b = a.mod(c);
        System.out.println(b);
        System.out.println(a);
    }
}
```

**Is there an easy way to remove all 0's from a number? That would be the easiest way to fix my problem**

Comment: Instead of computing the BigInteger factorial and then throwing away most of the digits, you can implement a special multiplication that only keeps the least significant non-zero digit in each step of the factorial computation, by applying modulo-arithmetic.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could just convert your number into a string and remove the zeros. Then you put it back into `BigInteger`:

```
public static BigInteger removeZeroes(int i) {
    return new BigInteger(String.valueOf(i).replace("0", ""));
}
```

Comment: Solved it! Thank you!

Comment: It should be   
`String str = String.valueOf(i).replace("0", "");`

`BigInteger bigInteger = new BigInteger(str.substring(str.length() - 1));`